# How to setting a favicon in pod2html

Tags: html, perl, perl-pod

I documented some perl files with POD and made a webpage with `pod2html`. Is it possible to set a **favicon** to that?

```pl
=pod

=encoding UTF-8

=begin pod2html

<link rel="..." type="..." href="/...">

=end pod2html

=cut
```

But there is nothing in my html file about this favicon.

And where have I put this image to? Is it possible to put it in the perl file directly?

Comment: Having read [the source](https://metacpan.org/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.34.0/source/ext/Pod-Html/lib/Pod/Html.pm) I don't think that is possible. The only things you can pass in for the `<head>` tag are the title and the URL for a single CSS stylesheet. I think you need to post-process the output.

Comment: So I have to build my own POD translator?

Comment: No, I would probably subclass the module that `pod2html` uses under the hood, and add post-processing to inject the favicon. Then make your own `pod2html` script that uses your module rather than the original one, and use that.

Comment: @simbabque Ah, a little batch script calling _pod2html_ and then calling _sed_ for example to put `<link ...` into the resulting html-file.

Comment: That could work too. But I was thinking of a proper Perl subclass. But the one function inside that module does everything including producing the file, so it might be easier to do what you've proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little batch script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pod2html my_pod_file.pl > my_html.html

sed -i '/<title/{ a <link rel="..." type="..." href="/..." />
; :label n; b label } my_html.html
```

`sed -i '/<title/a <link ... ' my_html.html` would work too, but then sed adds a line after all title tags.

---

If you use `$1` instead of `my_pod_file.pl` and `$2` instead of `my_html.html`, you can call your script like `./my_script my_pod_file.pl my_html.html`.

---

Instead of "sed" you can use "ed":

```sh
ed my_html.html << EOF
/<title/a
<link ...
.
wq
EOF
```

Thanks to [ubuntuusers.de](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/bash-text-in-eine-datei-hinter-bestimmter-zeil/)